# Multiple Charsets Issue

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I've tried a few things such as str replace, changing the charset etc but I can't get anything to work properly.

**Problem**
Items have been uploaded to the database with no charset. I've now added the charset to make sure this doesn't happen again. Now I need to fix the items that are in the database. I'm finding it difficult because sometimes they're uploaded on a MAC, other times Windows so there's a couple of charsets in there meaning I'm struggling with the strreplace.

Here are a couple of entries **with no charset** to make it clear:

1. â€œThis new development will not only offer a range of private and affordable housing but with the extensive commercial offerings including a family pub and restaurant and community centre, we are also creating an exemplary development which will bring long-lasting benefits to the wider community.â€
2. “Everyone was so friendly and it was heartening to see so much interest in the art of baking.”
3. Looking at thisÂ brand new â€˜modelâ€™ Cascada makes me think ofÂ otherÂ â€˜super modelsâ€™Â like Kate Moss and Heidi Klum.

The same items if I add  the UTF-8 charset:

1. “This new development will not only offer a range of private and affordable housing but with the extensive commercial offerings including a family pub and restaurant and community centre, we are also creating an exemplary development which will bring long-lasting benefits to the wider community.”
2. �Everyone was so friendly and it was heartening to see so much interest in the art of baking.�
3. Looking at this brand new ‘model’ Cascada makes me think of other ‘super models’ like Kate Moss and Heidi Klum.

I know that I'm going to need to edit every entry in the database. But everything I've tried so far outputs a special character in one way or another.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Quite embarrassing but I managed to fix this in PHPMYADMIN. It turned out the field names were set to latin1_swedish_ci so I changed this to utf8_bin and it appears to have fixed the problem.